# Consecutive str search in text file python

Tags: python, string, search, text

I am trying to write a script for analyzing lp files of a pyomo model. I want to first list all the constraints which appearing in lp file. Here is a small piece of the lp file:

```
\* Source Pyomo model name=urbs *\

min 
obj:
+1 costs(Environmental)
+1 costs(Fixed)
+1 costs(Fuel)
+1 costs(Invest)
+1 costs(Variable)

s.t.

c_e_res_vertex(1_Mid_Biomass_Stock)_:
+1 e_co_stock(1_Mid_Biomass_Stock)
-1 e_pro_in(1_Mid_Biomass_plant_Biomass)
= 0

c_e_res_vertex(1_Mid_Coal_Stock)_:
+1 e_co_stock(1_Mid_Coal_Stock)
-1 e_pro_in(1_Mid_Coal_plant_Coal)
= 0
```

**So if the lp file is like the one above then my script should print out or write in a text file following lines**:

```
res_vertex(1_Mid_Biomass_Stock)
res_vertex(1_Mid_Coal_Stock)
```

I found out every constraint starts with `'c_e_'` and ends with `')_'`, so I wrote the following string for getting the first constraint `res_vertex(1_Mid_Biomass_Stock)`:

```
with open('lp_file.lp', 'r') as lp:
    lp = lp.read().replace('\n', ' ')
    lp = str(lp[lp.find('c_e_')+4:
                lp.find(')_')+1])
    print(lp)
```

Above code-piece actually prints out the first constraint, but I need to do this for the consecutive constraints (2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc...) with a for loop probably.

I cant force `.find()` to search after some index. So how would I solve this?

PS: Constraint names do not have same length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.match` with a pattern that extracts what's between `'c_e_'` and `')_'` (assuming `output_file` is the file object to write the output to):

```
import re
with open('lp_file.lp', 'r') as lp:
    for line in lp:
        match = re.match(r'c_e_(.*\))_', line)
        if match:
            print(match.group(1), file=output_file)
```